# How to create a Samba share that is writable from Windows without 777 permissions?

Tags: permissions, windows, samba, chmod, shared-folders

I have a path on a Linux machine (Debian 8) which I want to share with Samba 4 to Windows computers (Win7 and 8 in a domain). In my `smb.conf` I did the following:

```
[myshare]
path = /path/to/share
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
public = yes
```

I have perfect read access from Windows. But in order to have write access, I need to do `chmod -R 777 /path/to/share` in order to be able to write to it from Windows.

What I want is write access from Windows after I provide the Linux credentials of the Linux owner of `/path/to/share`.

I already tried:

```
[myshare]
path = /path/to/share
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
```

Then Windows asks for credentials, but no matter what I enter, it's always denied.

What is the correct way to gain write access to Samba shares from a Windows domain computer without granting 777 permissions?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I recommend to create a dedicated user for that share and specify it in `force user`[(see docs)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEUSER).

Create a user (`shareuser` for example) and set the owner of everything in the share folder to that user:

```
adduser --system shareuser
chown -R shareuser /path/to/share
```

Then add `force user` and permission mask settings in `smb.conf`:

```
[myshare]
path = /path/to/share
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = shareuser
```

Note that `guest ok` is a synonym for `public`.

Comment: I had a similar problem and all google searches showed the dirty way to simply use 777. I wanted 775 for my shared folder and I wanted files to be created using my linux "defaultUser", I used also public = yes. Folder was 775, create and dir mask was 775 but in Windows it was not writable and I could not get why. Adding `force user = defaultUser` did the job for me.

Comment: I can't get this to work, any time I try to share the directory, I just get a window telling me I need to give "others" write permission in order to share the directory.

Comment: I got it, the problem was the location of `smb.conf`. Google and even sambas documentation said the file should be at `/usr/local/samba/lib` but actually it is in `/etc/samba`

Comment: @MarkKramer It's a good idea to follow the documents included in your specific Linux distribution because many distros re-organize the files to fit the Linux Foundation's FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard).  I recommend reading and searching the docs delivered with your distro because google's not always the best answer, for example you may get info for a different version of the software.  Best Regards.

Comment: Why is a dedicated share user recommended exactly?

Comment: This approach worked for me where nothing else I read or tried had. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In the share settings in `smb.conf`, you'll need to specify the names of users and/or groups that are allowed to write to the share, using a `write list = ...` line.

Example:

```
[myshare]
...
write list = my_linux_username
```

---

Then you'll need to use the `smbpasswd` command to set up a password to authenticate `my_linux_username` for Samba:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a my_linux_username
```

This step is necessary because the standard system passwords in `/etc/shadow` are hashed in algorithms that are incompatible with the password hash algorithms used in the SMB protocol. When a client sends a SMB authentication packet, it includes a hashed password. It can only be compared to another password hash that uses the same algorithm.

(Very, very old instructions from the previous millennium may recommend disabling password encryption in Samba, and using certain registry hacks to allow Windows to emit unencrypted passwords to the network. This advice is *obsolete*: those registry hacks may no longer work in current versions of Windows, and allow anyone who can monitor your network traffic to trivially capture your password.)

---

There's one more thing you may have to do client-side. When your Windows client system is joined to an Active Directory domain and you're logged in with an AD account, it automatically prefixes all unqualified usernames with the name of the AD domain of the user, i.e. you will be authenticating as `AD_DOMAIN\your_username`, not just `your_username`.

If you are logged in with a local account (or your client system is not joined to an AD domain), Windows may automatically prefix the username with the *client hostname* unless you specify another domain name.

To successfully log in to a stand-alone Samba server from a stand-alone Windows client, you may have to specify your username as `SAMBA_SERVER_HOSTNAME\your_username`.

Otherwise Samba will see the username as `WINDOWS_CLIENT_HOSTNAME\your_username`, conclude that it has no way to verify any users belonging to domain named `WINDOWS_CLIENT_HOSTNAME`, and will reject the login.

(Newer versions of Samba *may* have a built-in check for this specific situation, and they might allow you access nevertheless. But this is basically how SMB authentication works "under the hood", and if you need to deal with old versions of Samba, it might be useful still.)

Comment: \username also works in windows . with only one backslash

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this because I was in a hurry and didn't even had time to focus on creating users and so...

Just had to take out the data of a debian 9 machine as soon as possible and this was the fastest way I tought of, if you want to avoid skipping commands you can also do this but **it is obviously not recommended** unless you're in a **hurry**.

```
[mymfolder]
path = /mymfolder
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
force user = root
```

Comment: And if you go this route you can restrict by host using the "hosts allow" option. See: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/server_security.html

Answer (score 2):

Basic working setup in my case (using SAMBA guest feature, /myfolder access rights suitable for **[your_SAMBA-Unix_share_user_account]**):

```
[global]
guest account = [your_SAMBA-Unix_share_user_account]

[mymfolder]
path = /myfolder
browseable = yes
read only =no
guest ok =yes
```

Is important to disconnect any other mapped drives in Windows machine to this SAMBA server as it appears that it is not allowed to have more than single logged on user at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by yaegashi suggests:

```
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    force user = shareuser
```

But that did not work for me. I followed the advice in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600026/samba-share-with-force-user-is-still-not-writable-unless-files-have-777-permis/750152#750152) which worked:

```
    create mask = 0660
    directory mask = 0770
    force user = shareuser
```

You also have to set the share permissions correctly, see [original answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600026/samba-share-with-force-user-is-still-not-writable-unless-files-have-777-permis/750152#750152).