Samba permission - Linux Mint from Windows 11
I am running a Samba 4.19.5 samba server on a Linux Mint box. I want to connect from a Windows 11 PC to an external HDD (FAT format).
The configuration section of the folder is  below:
 [Share]
   path = /media/Owner/Elements/MM/TV-S

   public = yes
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no

I can see the share from the Windows 11 PC, but it says I do not have permission to view the folder.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for answers.

Probably samba runs as a user that doesn't have access. FAT does not have ownership information, so it's generally mounted with access only for the user that mounts it (Owner in your case, according to path).

What user did you assign for  "guest"  access? Also, you're aware that Win11 doesn't like unauthenticated shares, aren't you

... So you'll probably need force user to ensure that regardless of the account Win11 has used to authenticate to Samba it can access the mount point

I didn't assign any user for "guest". guest should be like everybody, I thought.

@veliizzet: Windows is definitely not like nix when it comes to accessing unauthenticated resources. This seems to be a duplicate of the following: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206309/how-to-create-a-samba-share-that-is-writable-from-windows-without-777-permission https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206310
